# Does anyone know if there's a PAM data library for prawn/shrimp behavioural noises?

Tags: pam, dataset, invertebrates

First stack exchange post ever, please excuse any breach of convention. Has anyone seen any PAM libraries containing noises from prawn (Penaeus Monodon specifically) or shrimps?

Answer (score 3):

Searching scholar.google I found a 2013 publication by Smith and Tabrett on "The use of passive acoustics to measure feed consumption by Penaeus monodon (giant tiger prawn) in cultured systems". I would suggest to ask the authors if they can help you with some recordings.